# How do I insert a line break into text loaded from yaml?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, yaml

I'm using Ruby v.1.8.7 and Rails v.3.1.3 to create a website and I'm loading the text on the pages from a yml file. I have text inside of a `<h3>` tag but I want the third sentence to be placed on a separate line without having to do an explicit check in the html.

For instance, I have:

```
<h3><%= Settings.text_from_yml %></h3>
```

in my view and text_from_yaml looks like:

`This is the first sentence. This is the second. And lastly, the third.`

inside the yml file. Is there a way I can place a line break in the string inside the yml file to guarantee the third sentence will be on its own line? I've tried placing `<br />` before the third line but that just outputs the text "`<br /> And lastly, the third.`"

I've also tried doing

```
<h3><%= Settings.text_from_yml.html_safe %></h3>
```

but that didn't do what I wanted. Is there some other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<h3><%= raw Settings.text_from_yml %></h3>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to do what I want either. It acts the same as "html_safe" and outputs the line break as a string.

Comment: html_safe and raw are not the same.  html_safe only wraps the string in ActiveSupport::Safebuffer instead of actually marking the string as safe.  Here is a good read on html_safe: http://techspry.com/ruby_and_rails/html_safe-and-helpers-in-rails-3-mystery-solved/